# How do i make a menu that's not toggled to be toggled by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using the theme Pixeladmin (http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB07403R9)
As you might see when you open the page the menu is open now I want it to be closed and I have no clue what to change.

I'd like to have it closed by default instead of open.

I'm graceful for your answers, thank you once again!

Comment: It would be easy to work if we have your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need this!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').addClass('mmc')
});
```

When I inspected the element and toggle happened `body` was the only change that took place by adding/removing class to it!! By default this class will not be there which says `menu` is open and if you add this `mmc` class to `body` menu will go to close state with animation!

---

**Update**

On more inspection I found out that the event for click is present in `pixel-admin.min.js` file and below is the code that gets executed on that event.

```
$("#main-menu-toggle").on("click",$.proxy(this.toggle,this))
```

I don't have much idea on `$.proxy` jquery function but below is what documentation says

> **Takes a function and returns a new one that will always have a
>   particular context.**

Explanation about the functionality of `proxy` is always welcome!

**[Source for $.proxy](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)**

Now your styles for `.mmc` class has been defined in `pixel-admin.min.css` and the minified version of file are always difficult to debug so I am not able to gather much information on that! If you get full version of above files then you can debug yourself to understand in a better way!

Comment: Hey, when I added this it worked but the problem is my menu is dark for some reason then as you might see here: http://prntscr.com/7ytk5x

Also how come mmc closes the menu?

Comment: There is some functionality added in one of the js files by the developer so which just identifies whether body has `mmc` class or not and based on its presence or absence menu display changes! I can give you detailed information only when I can see all the code. In fact you should analyze what is happening when it is clicked and what all are changes takes place by debugging!! Still I did not understand what is the problem you are having with darker menu!! Image did not help much to understand!!

Comment: Regarding your dark menu the reason might be existence of any other cusom styles done by you because if you execute the same code in the site link given by you, there will not be any changes as you could see!!

Answer (score 1):

One hack would be to simulate a click to the toggle button, when the page loads.

```
$(function() {
    $("#main-menu-toggle").click();
});
```

Comment: Hi @John Bupit, Where would I add this to the index.html ?

Comment: Enclose it in a `<script>` tag and place it inside the `<head>` tag. But I would prefer Guruprasad's solution over mine.

Comment: Wonderful it works aswell but my menu goes dark after adding it for some reason as you might see here http://prntscr.com/7ytk5x